# Why can i only see the read-me when i try to host a project with github pages?

Tags: reactjs, github

I was trying to host an older project written is **react.js** using **github pages** but when i open it all i see is the read-me. Can someone help me?

https://github.com/Andreiosup/PathfindingVisualizer/
https://andreiosup.github.io/PathfindingVisualizer/

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is looking in the root folder for "index.html" and defaulting to the readme when it doesn't find it.

if using create-react-app, this documentation should help out:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Answer (score 0):

First you create the build then push the code into your Git repository.

Your repository needs an index.html file to run your project.

If the git repository does not have the index.html file, use the git repository readme file.